# Ubuntu 21.10 - Attaching google cloud file to an email

Tags: email, 21.10

I mounted **google drive** and I see all my files.

when attaching a file to an email it's **original filename and file extension is lost**, so the recipient can not open the file.(attachment of test.jpg turns to hdskjhfkjdahskfjhskdjfhkjsdh so the recipient does NOT know the original file name or extension)

pls advise

Comment: How have you mounted the Google Drive? Which 3rd party unofficial software are you using? If none then you must be talking about the Gnome/Files integration and that isn't an actual drive. It may work if you copy the file (download it actually) to somewhere else and then attach it to whatever email client you're using. Of course it should work as is and completely independent of the OS if doing it in the Gmail webmail.

Comment: Details are unclear or missing altogether. Are you using Gmail? Are you sure you didn't accidentally type over the name of the file? `hdskjhfkjdahskfjhskdjfhkjsdh` isn't a randomly generated filename, it looks like someone continually mashed all the keys on the home row.

Comment: I "mounted" or actually linked my google drive with Gnome/files integration, I know it is not the "actual" drive but just a link to it. downloading a file and attaching the uploaded file works fine. but I'm trying to imitate the windows way of attaching files ...

Comment: *I'm trying to imitate the windows way of attaching files* Don't, because you can't and you should know why from the first comment. This is a non-issue and a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience using Gnome/file integration on a new Ubuntu 22.04. It is time consuming to download on HD and add the download as an attachment in TB (91.11.0 (64 bits)).
I signed-off the google online account and installed google-drive-ocamlfuse as explained in https://linuxhint.com/google_drive_installation_ubuntu/, which was working fine in my former PC.